# Button to store data from one table to another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a funding table in which there is a field name_of_organisation which displays a list of organisations from organisation table. In the list I have an option "Not Listed". If notlisted is selected a further form opens to add organisation. But that organisation details get added in the funding table. What I want is on funding show page if new organisation details are added admin can verify the organisation details and should have a button to click on so that all those organisation details in funding table get added in the organisation table. I need help with query for add organisation button on show.html.erb page for funding to add organisation details from funding to organisation table.

schema for funding table

```
create_table "fundings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "type_of_activity"
    t.string "season"
    t.text "activity_details"
    t.string "name_of_organisation"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "province"
    t.string "postal_code"
    t.string "telephone_number"
    t.text "address"
    t.integer "organisation_id"
    end
```

schema for organisation table

```
create_table "organisations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name_of_organisation"
t.text "address"
t.string "city"
t.string "province"
t.string "postal_code"
t.string "telephone_number"
end
```

Show.html.erb (funding)

```
<%unless @funding.organisation.blank?%>
    <p><strong>Name of the Organisation:</strong>
    <%= @funding&.organisation&.name_of_organisation %></p><br>
  <%end%>

<% if @funding.name_of_organisation.present? %>
 <%= @funding.name_of_organisation %>
  <% if current_user.superadmin? %>
    <%= link_to 'Add Organisation', '' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @max  I already have organisation_id in the funding table. I already have the associations you just posted. I had not posted the complete schema. I have edited it. Check it out

Comment: That's only part of what you need to do. Store data in one table, don't save the same thing in multiple places.

Comment: @RobertBuchberger There is a need to store things at multiple places. App requirement. Just need help to figureout how can a button store data from one table to another.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ID of the organization instead of the name to link the two models together. Thats how associations in ActiveRecord work.

Your attempt has a huge flaw in that editing the name of the organization would break any assocation. IDs don't change.

Start by generating a migration to add a foreign key column to the fundings table:

```
# rails g migration add_organization_to_fundings organization:belongs_to
how class AddOrganizationToFundings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :fundings, :organization, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

If you have any existing data that is linked by the name you need to iterate through and fix these records:

```
Funding.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |f|
  organization = Organization.find_by(name: f.name_of_organisation)
  f.update!(organization_id: organization.id)
end
```

You should then write a migration to remove the `fundings.name_of_organisation` column.

You then need to setup the proper assocations:

```
class Funding < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fundings
end
```

You can then create a select tag by using the form option helpers:

```
<%= form_for(@funding) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :organization_id, Organization.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Funding is also a very strange model name as its uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's infuriating when you ask "How do I do this?" on stackoverflow and they say "Don't", but in this instance it's pretty cut and dry. Don't do it this way.

You're storing the organization name and address and such twice, once for the funding and once for the organization. This is a very bad practice, which will bite you when it comes time to change anything at all. You want to store the organization details the organization table, and that table only. Strip it out of your funding table, and add a foreign key to reference which organization it belongs to.

These are pretty basic concepts, you really want to take a little time and learn about databases before going further. Find a decent lecture, article, or tutorial on "relational database basics" and work through it. It doesn't have to be (and probably won't be) specific to rails.

After that, read up on [Activerecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), especially relations.

To solve your admin approval problem, what I would do is add an "approved" boolean flag to the organization table and a custom controller action only available to admins to approve it. You can go further and create an "approved" scope for normal users, and a "pending" scope or something visible to admins. That's only one possible solution of many, though.

Answer (score -1):

In order to 'Add Organisation' .. I would run get the path to the method of logic you're trying to do and `remote:true` the logic depending if you're planning to render with js or redirect to a new screen.